# Setting parameters conditionally in symfony

Tags: symfony

Is there a way to set a parameter in symfony based on a certain condition, f.e. an ENV var?
Expression language came to my mind but it seems its only supported in *arguments*, *properties* and *calls*

config.yml:

```
parameters:
  env(CI): false
  ci: '%env(CI)%'
  database_host: "@=parameter(ci) ? 'localhost' : 'mysql'"

doctrine:
  dbal:
    connections:
      cms:
        host:     "%database_host%"
```

**UPDATE**
Expression language doesnt work in that case (Up to SF 3.3 currently) so i used Oli's approach which works:
get_params_from_env.php:

```
$container->setParameter('database_host', 'mysql');
if (getenv('CI')) {
    $container->setParameter('database_host', '127.0.0.1');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line to config.yml:

```
imports:
    - { resource: get_params_from_env.php }
```

Then, in the php file, use this:

```
<?php
$container->setParameter('app.dummy_var', getenv('DUMMY_VAR'));
```

You can read about including your own PHP files here, under 'advanced techniques': http://symfony.com/doc/current/configuration/configuration_organization.html

Comment: It's a bit unclear where does this new file needs to be created and where it's being imported from